# WM Application works as expected in WM Professional 6,6.1 but not properly in Wm 6.5 Professional devices

Tags: windows-mobile

I have developed WM application using WM SDK 6 and it works as expected on WM 6, 6.1 Professional devices/emulators.
But when I run the same application on WM 6.5 professional emulators, it has some GUI problems like..
 (a) Web browser control does not display progress bar at bottom and scroll bars.
 (b) Cursor.WaitCursor does not work.
 (c) List view does not display gradient effect.
While above all work fine in 6.0 and 6.1.
As I know there is no any SDK changes in 6.5 then why the same is not working?
Am I missing something that should be taken care for WM 6.5 especially?
Please help me to find some solution.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can give you is that you need to test and conditionally perform some operations depending on the device used.  I have found that devices with only a different build number can have differnet behaivour.

the problems for me are caused by the OEM who created a version of the OS for each HH.  the last problem I had was that Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status gave unreliable information and the only solution was to use the SDK for the device to get the same information.